# Multiple JPanel inside another

Tags: java, jpanel

[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXiOt.png)
I have to make a format like this, like make a 1,2 panel, then put a 3,1 panel on the left side. Then, I put 4 text fields in the middle left panel and one button in the bottom left panel.

I'm not sure if I can just use GridLayout or if I have to use BorderLayout too.

How can I get this organized because when I set it up, I can't get the layout right. The textfields are not in the right position, they end up on the right side.

```js
public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector projectList;
   private JButton button1;
   private ProjectSpendingPanel spendingPanel;

   private JFrame frame1;
   JPanel panel1;
   JPanel leftPanel;
   JPanel subPanel;

   GridLayout layout1;
   BorderLayout layout2;
   GridLayout layout3;

   JLabel message;
   JLabel labelName;
   JLabel labelNumber;
   JLabel labelLocation;
   JLabel labelFunding;

   JTextField textField1;
   JTextField textField2;
   JTextField textField3;
   JTextField textField4;

 //Constructor initializes components and organize them using certain layouts
 public CreatePanel(Vector projectList, ProjectSpendingPanel spendingPanel)
  {
    this.projectList = projectList;
    this.spendingPanel = spendingPanel;
 //organize components here
 layout1 = new GridLayout(1,2);
 layout2 = new BorderLayout(1,3);
 layout3 = new GridLayout(4,2);
 this.setLayout(layout1);

 panel1 = new JPanel(layout1);
 leftPanel = new JPanel(layout3);
 subPanel = new JPanel(layout2);

 add(panel1);
 panel1.add(subPanel);
 panel1.add(leftPanel);

 labelName = new JLabel("Project Name");
 leftPanel.add(labelName);
 textField1 = new JTextField("", 15);
    leftPanel.add(textField1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

 labelName = new JLabel("Project Number");
 leftPanel.add(labelName);
 textField2 = new JTextField("",15);
 leftPanel.add(textField2);

 labelLocation = new JLabel("Project Location");
 leftPanel.add(labelLocation);
 textField3 = new JTextField("",15);
 leftPanel.add(textField3);

 labelFunding = new JLabel("Initial Funding");
 leftPanel.add(labelFunding);
 textField4 = new JTextField("",15);
 leftPanel.add(textField4);

 add(leftPanel);
    button1 = new JButton("Create a project");
    subPanel.add(button1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }
```

Comment: can you post code you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you probably intended, you need to tweak your code just a little.

Your lines

```
panel1 = new JPanel(layout1);
leftPanel = new JPanel(layout3);
subPanel = new JPanel(layout2);
```

should be altered to read

```
panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
leftPanel = new JPanel(layout3);
subPanel = new JPanel(layout2);
```

`GridLayout` takes rows first, then columns. Your `layout1` defines one row and two columns but you use it for the text fields and the button, so I assume the two panels need to be above each other.

Second, you need to change the order from

```
add(panel1);
panel1.add(subPanel);
panel1.add(leftPanel);
```

to

```
add(panel1);
panel1.add(leftPanel);
panel1.add(subPanel);
```

Finally, I think you need to change

```
add(leftPanel);
button1 = new JButton("Create a project");
```

to

```
add(spendingPanel);
button1 = new JButton("Create a project");
```

Adding `leftPanel`again seems to destroy the layout. If you do not want to see your `spendingPanel` here, you could use `new JPanel()` instead.

Here is a [screenshot of the running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5lkR.png)